# Как сделать кнопку с изображением?

Tags: c++, css, qt

У меня есть QButton, которая должна быть в виде галочки. Как это реализовать? Есть галочка сделанная при помощи css, но как ее наложить. Какие еще варианты есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам просто нужно, чтобы на кнопке отображалась галочка, то используйте текст с символом юникода: "✓".

Их можно найти на [этом сайте](https://unicode-table.com/ru/).